# How to remove permissions for ios using expo

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, expo

I have an app using expo, but I want to remove NSMicrophoneUsageDescription from de infoplist.

Using this command  `expo config --type introspect`
I got

```
 ios: {
   ....
    config: {
     ....
    },
    infoPlist: {
      ....
      NSCameraUsageDescription: 'Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera',
      NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription: 'Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos',
      NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: 'Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone',
     ...
}
```

my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/config": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.4.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.4.2",
    "expo-clipboard": "~2.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~12.1.3",
    "expo-crypto": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.6.3",
    "expo-device": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~2.4.2",
    "expo-localization": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.13.3",
    "expo-random": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.15",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.0.9",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.2",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.8.7",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.2.0",
    "ts-interface-builder": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-interface-checker": "^1.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```

So, I want to remove unused permissions as **NSMicrophoneUsageDescription** but I don't know how, can you help me?

I read the documentation in expo for permissions but it says that the plugins has its own configurations for permissions but it does not say somenthing about remove them
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved updating SDK to 45 and expo-image-picker to it more recent version, here you can modify in the app.json like this

```
 [
    "expo-image-picker",
    {
      "microphonePermission": false
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to deploy your app. If you are not requesting permission in your whole app.js, you dont have to do anything to remove the permission in the general.

In my experience, the apple store connects will still approve your app. On the apple store download page, the description will not show any permission required.

If I guess wrong and you just want to remove the permission, I recommend you eject the app. It will give you more flexibility to control the infoPlist.